# MySQL and SQL Server terminology

Tags: mysql, sql-server, terminology

In SQL Server we have:

```
Instance->Database->Schema->Objects (tables etc)
```

I'm confused what the MySQL equivalents are, specifically "database" and "schema". From what I can tell it's something like:

```
| SQL Server | MySQL    |
|------------|----------|
| Instance   | Instance |
| Database   | Schema   |
| Schema     | N/A      |
| Objects    | Objects  |
```

How far wrong am I?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh dear I got a downvote. I wish I knew why, because then I could fix it. Driveby downvotes give me a sad. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/211616:

> In MySQL, the two are equivalent.  The keyword DATABASE or DATABASES
> can be replaced with SCHEMA or SCHEMAS wherever it appears. Examples:
>
> CREATE DATABASE <=> CREATE SCHEMA
>
> SHOW DATABASES <=> SHOW SCHEMAS

For what it is worth, this is the case in Oracle as well.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL database/schema are synonyms, so your approach is ok.